# Rails: How to access properties in builder object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, I have this code in my project

```
    <%= stammdaten_form.fields_for :ehrenamtsnachweis do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'ehrenamtsnachwei_fields', f: builder %>
    <% end %>
```

And when I give a break point in `rubymine editor` on the line render I see this builder object and when I expand it looks like the image below. Now, I need the `id` and `stammdaten_id` under `@values`, see bottom of the image. How can I access this `id` and `stammdaten_id` and I want to pass them to the partial `ehrenamtsnachwei_fields` when I render it.

I tried

```
builder[:id], builder[:values] and builder[:object]
```

But I get this error `undefined method [] for ..`. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ehrenamtsnachwei_fields` partial you will have an object `f` which is your builder (as that's the key you've passed it through as).

`f.object` will give you the ActiveRecord instance that the fields builder is for.

Is that what you're after?